# split path name to get routing parameter

Tags: javascript, url-parsing

i am using mvc and jquery in my application i have the routing url like this :

```
ID/Controller/Action
```

I want to get the URL and split it to get the id in jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  var appId = pathname.split('/')[1];
```

i see that your first param is the id with this piece of code you can get the id in jquery

Answer (score 14):

You can split the pathname from the moment you get it:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```

Once you have it split, you can access any part of the pathname as follows:

```
var path_id = pathname[1];
var path_controller = pathname[2];
var path_action = pathname[3];
```